# JS: Get the .html() of selected datalist option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, datalist

I have the following code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- add jquery -->

CITY<br>
<input id='cities' type="text" list="list_items">
<datalist id="list_items">
  <option value='Kent'>WA</option> <!-- PLEASE NOTE THAT THERE ARE REPEATING CITY NAMES -->
  <option value='Kent'>DE</option>
  <option value='New York City'>NY</option> <!-- AND REPEATING STATE NAMES -->
  <option value='Liverpool'>NY</option>
  <option value='Brentford'>SD</option>
</datalist>
<br><br>

STATE<br>
<input id='states' type="text" disabled>

<script>
  $('#cities').on('change', function(val) {
    $('#states').val(val.html())
  })
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pxcc1vn4/3/

I am trying to make it so that I can select an item from a `datalist` and have the value of the selected `datalist` `option` be in the first `input` and have the `.html()` of the selected `datalist` `option` be placed in the second `input`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.Select value form the first list and set that in second

```
    $('#cities').on('change', function(event) {
      $("#states").val(event.target.value);
     })
```

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58o157sg/4/)

Comment: Have you tried to click out of the input after you selected? The change event will only trigger after that.

Comment: @XYZ No. It is just returning the name of the city instead of the state.

Comment: @ChrisChen What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick.

```
$('#cities').on('change', function() {
    $('#states').val($(this).text())
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/
vs 
http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: This doesn't work. It just returns the name of the city.

Comment: My bad, you can change $(this).val() to .text()

Comment: My bad, didn't notice you are using datalist attribute. Instead of work out your problem. I'd actually suggest to use https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ to achieve the same functions instead of datalist due to compatibility issue. Please refer to http://html.com/attributes/input-list/ to consider it

Answer (score 0):

You should use `val.currentTarget.value`

```js
$('#cities').on('change', function(val) {
  debugger;
    
     var selectedValue = $("#list_items").find("option[value='"+val.currentTarget.value+"']").prop('outerHTML');
$('#states').val(selectedValue);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- add jquery -->

CITY<br>
<input id='cities' type="text" list="list_items">
<datalist id="list_items">
  <option value='Kent WA'>WA</option>
  <option value='Kent DE'>DE</option>
  <option value='New York City'>NY</option>
  <option value='Liverpool'>NY</option>
  <option value='Brentford'>SD</option>
</datalist>
<br><br>
STATE<br>
<input id='states' type="text" >
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It just returns the name of the city.

Comment: @MakPo i have udpated my answer please check it'll work for you i thought you just need selected value rather than whole HTML

Comment: That isn't working and the point is, I want there to be able to have duplicate city names. In this small bit of code, there are only a few repeating city names, but in my actual code there are hundreds of cities and a lot of them are repeating.

Comment: @MakPo than you must have to find any alternate way instead of DataList because `:selected` does not work on datalist options, as one datalist can provide suggestions for multiple inputs. If two different inputs contain two different suggestions from the list, which would be the selected one? or you just have to remove duplicate city names or edit city name as i have done my snippet

Answer (score 0):

Don't use same value for two options

Look at this https://jsfiddle.net/pxcc1vn4/12/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- add jquery -->

CITY<br>
<input id='cities' type="text" list="list_items">
<datalist id="list_items">
  <option value='Kent In WA'>WA</option>
  <option value='Kent In DE'>DE</option>
  <option value='New York City'>NY</option>
  <option value='Liverpool'>NY</option>
  <option value='Brentford'>SD</option>
```

STATE

```
$('#cities').on('change', function(event) {

    $('#states').val($('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').html())
})
```

Comment: I want there to be able to have duplicate city names. In this small bit of code, there are only a few repeating city names, but in my actual code there are hundreds of cities and a lot of them are repeating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet,

HTML CODE :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- add jquery -->

CITY<br>
<input id='cities' type="text" list="list_items">
<datalist id="list_items">
  <option value='Kent'>WA</option>
  <option value='Kent'>DE</option>
  <option value='New York City'>NY</option>
  <option value='Liverpool'>NY</option>
  <option value='Brentford'>SD</option>
</datalist>
<br><br>
STATE<br>
<input id='states' type="text" disabled>
```

JS CODE :

```
$(document).on("input", "#cities", function(){
  var val = this.value;

  if($('#list_items').find('option').filter(function(){
        return this.value.toUpperCase() === val.toUpperCase();        
    }).length) {
        //send ajax request
        $("#states").val(this.value);
    }
});
```

And here is working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxcc1vn4/15/)

**EDIT**

HTML CODE :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- add jquery -->

CITY<br>
<input id='cities' type="text" list="list_items">
<datalist id="list_items">
  <option value='Kent'>WA</option>
  <option value='Kent'>DE</option>
  <option value='New York City'>NY</option>
  <option value='Liverpool'>NY</option>
  <option value='Brentford'>SD</option>
</datalist>
<br><br>
STATE<br>
<input id='states' type="text" disabled>
<input id='secondinput' type="text" disabled>
```

JS CODE :

```
$(document).on("input", "#cities", function(){
  var val = this.value;

  if($('#list_items').find('option').filter(function(){
        return this.value.toUpperCase() === val.toUpperCase();        
    }).length) {
        //send ajax request
        $("#states").val(this.value);
        $("#secondinput").val($("#list_items option[value='"+this.value+"']").text());
    }


});
```

This is working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxcc1vn4/17/)

Comment: This just returns the name of the city instead of the state.

Comment: Try to select 'Kent' 'DE' the result is 'WADE'. It is concatenating 'WA' and 'DE'.